Separating a Dataframe Column by Multiple Delimiters Into New Columns Using Pandas
I have a table similar to the one below where I have a summary column with groups and an associated value separated by a colon where each separate group with its value is separated by a comma. (group1:value1,group2:value2...).
  Area       DTTM ID ID2                        Summary
0    M   1/1/1960  A   A                         1:2980
1    M   3/8/2021  A   B                         1:2980
2    M  5/12/2024  A   B                         1:8732
3    M   1/1/1960  A   C                         1:8732
4    H   3/8/2021  B   C                 1:53174,9:2332
5    H  5/12/2024  B   D                  1:22017,9:118
6    H   1/1/1960  B   A  1:4239, 6:184, 9:1243, 14:482

I am trying to separate the summary column into separate columns for each group (the number before the colons) and include the value (number after the colons) in each column for each row. How can I go about this? A sample output is show below:
  Area       DTTM ID ID2   Bin1  Bin6  Bin9  Bin14
0    M   1/1/1960  A   A   2980     0     0      0
1    M   3/8/2021  A   B   2980     0     0      0
2    M  5/12/2024  A   B   8732     0     0      0
3    M   1/1/1960  A   C   8732     0     0      0
4    H   3/8/2021  B   C  53174     0  2332      0
5    H  5/12/2024  B   D  22017     0   118      0
6    H   1/1/1960  B   A   4239   184  1243    482


Is the Summary a column of dictionaries or strings?

The summary column is a string

IIUC, extractall and pivot, then join:
out = df.join(df['Summary'].str.extractall(r'(\d+):(\d+)')
              .astype(int)
              .droplevel(1).pivot(columns=0, values=1)
              .fillna(0).astype(int)
              .add_prefix('Bin')
             ).drop(columns='Summary')

Output:
  Area       DTTM ID ID2   Bin1  Bin6  Bin9  Bin14
0    M   1/1/1960  A   A   2980     0     0      0
1    M   3/8/2021  A   B   2980     0     0      0
2    M  5/12/2024  A   B   8732     0     0      0
3    M   1/1/1960  A   C   8732     0     0      0
4    H   3/8/2021  B   C  53174     0  2332      0
5    H  5/12/2024  B   D  22017     0   118      0
6    H   1/1/1960  B   A   4239   184  1243    482


That's what I did first for my second option. Though only now realizing that sort_index is unnecessary there ;). Any idea why df.pivot doesn't have a fill_value parameter?

Oh I hadn't seen your second option. Yes, IDK why pivot doesn't have the same options, nor why index is mandatory in pivot_table…

Ugh, yeah, that is annoying too, having to reset the index there. Seems like both could be improved.

If you .astype('Int64') instead of .astype(int) then you avoid the implicit conversion to float as part of the pivot operation and thus avoid needing a second .astype(int) call.

This works well. Thank you very much.

Option 1 (literal_eval + pd.json_normalize)
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

out = (df.join(
    pd.json_normalize(
        ('{' + df.pop('Summary') + '}').apply(literal_eval)
        )
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
    .sort_index(axis=1)
    .add_prefix('Bin')
    )
    )

Output:
  Area       DTTM ID ID2   Bin1  Bin6  Bin9  Bin14
0    M   1/1/1960  A   A   2980     0     0      0
1    M   3/8/2021  A   B   2980     0     0      0
2    M  5/12/2024  A   B   8732     0     0      0
3    M   1/1/1960  A   C   8732     0     0      0
4    H   3/8/2021  B   C  53174     0  2332      0
5    H  5/12/2024  B   D  22017     0   118      0
6    H   1/1/1960  B   A   4239   184  1243    482

Explanation

Add curly brackets to values of df['Summary'] to turn them into dictionary strings. Apply literal_eval and pass to pd.json_normalize. Use df.pop to drop the original column.
Apply df.fillna and change the dtype to int (df.astype).
Now, sort the columns with df.sort_index and prefix 'Bin' (df.add_prefix).
Finally, use df.join to attach the result to df.


Option 2 (Series.str.extractall + df.pivot_table)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

out2 = df.join(
    df.pop('Summary')
    .str.extractall('(?P<col>\d+):(\d+)')
    .astype(int)
    .reset_index()
    .pivot_table(index='level_0', columns='col', values=1,
                 aggfunc='first', fill_value=0)
    .add_prefix('Bin')
    )

Output:
out2.equals(out)
# True

Explanation

Use df.pop as above, and apply Series.str.extractall to get the digits before and after : in two separate columns (naming the first col), adding df.astype to get integers. Regex explained here.
Now, use df.reset_index and apply df.pivot_table with aggfunc='first' (thus benefiting from fill_value parameter absent from df.pivot).
Finally, as above: add the prefix, and join to original df.


Data used
import pandas as pd

data = {'Area': {0: 'M', 1: 'M', 2: 'M', 3: 'M', 4: 'H', 5: 'H', 6: 'H'}, 
        'DTTM': {0: '1/1/1960', 1: '3/8/2021', 2: '5/12/2024', 3: '1/1/1960', 
                 4: '3/8/2021', 5: '5/12/2024', 6: '1/1/1960'}, 
        'ID': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'B', 5: 'B', 6: 'B'}, 
        'ID2': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'C', 5: 'D', 6: 'A'}, 
        'Summary': {0: '1:2980', 1: '1:2980', 2: '1:8732', 3: '1:8732', 
                    4: '1:53174,9:2332', 5: '1:22017,9:118', 
                    6: '1:4239, 6:184, 9:1243, 14:482'}
        }


A possible solution:
summary = (
    df.pop("Summary")
    .str.split(r",\s*", regex=True)
    .explode()
    .str.split(":", expand=True)
)
summary[0] = "Bin" + summary[0]
summary = summary.pivot(columns=0, values=1).fillna(0)

out = df.join(summary)

  Area       DTTM ID ID2   Bin1 Bin14 Bin6  Bin9
0    M   1/1/1960  A   A   2980     0    0     0
1    M   3/8/2021  A   B   2980     0    0     0
2    M  5/12/2024  A   B   8732     0    0     0
3    M   1/1/1960  A   C   8732     0    0     0
4    H   3/8/2021  B   C  53174     0    0  2332
5    H  5/12/2024  B   D  22017     0    0   118
6    H   1/1/1960  B   A   4239   482  184  1243


I'd suggest you use pure python to process the strings in the Summary column, and then reassign back to the original dataframe. You should get better performance, since these are strings.
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import zip_longest

box = defaultdict(list)
keys = {}

for num, entry in zip(df.index, df.Summary):
    split = entry.split(',')
    for value in split:
        value = value.strip().split(':')
        key, val = value
        box[num].append(val)
        keys[f"Bin{key}"] = 1

values = zip_longest(*box.values(), fillvalue=0)
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
(df
.drop(columns='Summary')
.assign(**dictionary)
)

  Area       DTTM ID ID2   Bin1  Bin9  Bin6  Bin14
0    M   1/1/1960  A   A   2980     0     0      0
1    M   3/8/2021  A   B   2980     0     0      0
2    M  5/12/2024  A   B   8732     0     0      0
3    M   1/1/1960  A   C   8732     0     0      0
4    H   3/8/2021  B   C  53174  2332     0      0
5    H  5/12/2024  B   D  22017   118     0      0
6    H   1/1/1960  B   A   4239   184  1243    482

Alternativey, you can create the dataframe, convert the dtypes, befor assigning back to the original dataframe:
dictionary = pd.DataFrame(dictionary).astype(int)
(df
.drop(columns='Summary')
.assign(**dictionary)
)

  Area       DTTM ID ID2   Bin1  Bin9  Bin6  Bin14
0    M   1/1/1960  A   A   2980     0     0      0
1    M   3/8/2021  A   B   2980     0     0      0
2    M  5/12/2024  A   B   8732     0     0      0
3    M   1/1/1960  A   C   8732     0     0      0
4    H   3/8/2021  B   C  53174  2332     0      0
5    H  5/12/2024  B   D  22017   118     0      0
6    H   1/1/1960  B   A   4239   184  1243    482

